# How can I debug multi-project using VS Code？

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I am working on a solution have several projects, you can see from following image:

[image]

And my question is I just can debug the main program but counld not debug the dependency project; Did it have any solutions to solve my problem? Can  anyone  give me reply?

Comment: you have to create separate solution for each project

Comment: no @viveknuna, You must create all project under same solution to debug through all simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution,just modify the project.json so that you can touch breakPoint at the dependency project;

```
    "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
```

value debugType as portable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I ran `node --inspect` on a separate port for each project separately. 
Run the command in the VS code terminal.
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075241/how-can-i-use-a-debug-launch-configuration-for-multi-root-workspaces-in-visual-c/58336940#58336940) for more details.